# sp_BlitzCache detecting thousands of executions of CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.CommandExecute (from Ola Hallengren's Maintenance Solution)

Tags: sql-server, maintenance, monitoring, sp-blitzcache

I recently implemented the Maintenance Solution as a nightly job in my company's database, via Windows Scheduler. It works as intended, except for one issue - the procedures are being created thousands of times despite the nightly task only executing them.

This is the script:

```
rem Run maintenance
sqlcmd -S censoredDatabaseName -E -Q "EXEC sp_Maintenance" > "censoredLogFolder"
rem Delete old files
PushD "censoredBackupLocation" && (forfiles -d -30 -c "cmd /c del /q @path") & PopD
```

And here is sp_Maintenance:

```
-- maintenance scripts stolen from Ola Hallengren

-- backup database to network drive
EXEC dbo.DatabaseBackup
@BackupType = 'FULL',
@Databases = 'USER_DATABASES',
@Directory = 'censoredBackupLocation'

-- optimise indexes
EXECUTE dbo.IndexOptimize
@Databases = 'USER_DATABASES',
-- Don't touch low fragmentation indexes
@FragmentationLow = NULL,
-- moderate/highly fragmented indexes are reorganised or rebuilt
@FragmentationMedium = 'INDEX_REORGANIZE,INDEX_REBUILD_ONLINE,INDEX_REBUILD_OFFLINE',
@FragmentationHigh = 'INDEX_REBUILD_ONLINE,INDEX_REBUILD_OFFLINE',
-- definition of fragmentation levels
@FragmentationLevel1 = 5,
@FragmentationLevel2 = 30,
-- don't bother for small indexes
@MinNumberOfPages = 100

-- refresh statistics
EXECUTE dbo.IndexOptimize
@Databases = 'USER_DATABASES',
-- skip index optimisation, it's done above
@FragmentationLow = NULL,
@FragmentationMedium = NULL,
@FragmentationHigh = NULL,
-- activate statistics commands
@UpdateStatistics = 'ALL'

-- check integrity of database
EXEC dbo.DatabaseIntegrityCheck
@Databases = 'ALL_DATABASES'
```

For reference, here is the top 5 queries from sp_BlitzCache. The task is run at 2am, the same time as listed for each of the `CREATE PROCEDURE` queries.

| Cost | Query Text | Warnings | # Executions | Total CPU (ms) | Last Execution |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | CREATE PROCEDURE sp_Maintenance AS … | Parameter Sniffing, Low Cost High CPU | 10 | 82396 | 22/12/2022 2:00 |
| 0.032869 | a SELECT query | Forced Serialization | 658864 | 61861 | 22/12/2022 8:02 |
| 0 | CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.IndexOptimize … | We couldn't find a plan for this query. More info on possible reasons: https://www.brentozar.com/go/noplans | 20 | 48377 | 22/12/2022 2:00 |
| 0 | CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.CommandExecute … | We couldn't find a plan for this query. More info on possible reasons: https://www.brentozar.com/go/noplans | 5422 | 47340 | 22/12/2022 2:00 |
| 0 | CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.CommandExecute … | We couldn't find a plan for this query. More info on possible reasons: https://www.brentozar.com/go/noplans | 58 | 30267 | 22/12/2022 2:00 |

It doesn't look like there is any `CREATE PROCEDURE` statements anywhere in my scripts, nor in any of the Maintenance Solution scripts. Is this something I need to be worried about? The company isn't international, so it's guaranteed that no one will be on the server when the maintenance job is running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case it does not show it is created lots of times, but that the Stored Procedure with that definition is being used lots of times.

You should see the statements (if it reaches the top x you are requesting).
Edit: Added pictures:

[image]

[image]

In these images, you see the PROC has been ran 100 times. Where the procedure call is being displayed in total, also the statement in it is being displayed.
Because this is not a production environment, I can get both, as nothing else runs on this machine.